# Extract a *.7z on Ubuntu, keeping the directory structure intact

Tags: ubuntu

How can I extract a *.7z file on Ubuntu while keeping the directory structure intact?

Following [this guide](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/7z-7zip-7za-file-compression/), I tried

```
7za e My.7z file.
```

But it does not keep the files in the SAME directory structure whith all the files at the parent directory.

Thank you.

Comment: Please include an example showing what you would _like_ to get and what is actually happening. Also, you have probably created the archive badly, make sure you compress the parent folder and not its contents, ie run `7za -a foo.7z /foo` and NOT `7za foo.7z -a /foo/*`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

```
7z x Myfile.7z
```

Comment: Yes, always use "x" to keep directory structures! Note that if you use the tag "e" f.eg 7z e Myfile.7z it will pile up all the FILES into your cwd without any directory. I experienced messing up all my existing files!